# Python: fsum for complex numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I'm coding a script performing sums over complex numbers, I'd like to spare myself the rounding errors and using an equivalent of `fsum` from the math library (which rejects complex number) over `numpy.sum` which seems to include rounding errors. There doesn't seem to have an equivalent in the math library. Of course I could separate real and imaginary parts and sum them separately, but is there a built-in (thus faster) function already doing it?

Comment: This appears to be related:  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2448

Comment: The [mpmath.fsum](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/general.html?highlight=fsum#mpmath.fsum) is rather good. mpmath does arbitrary precision arithmetic on reals and complex numbers.